# Spark sql : how to count double values

Tags: apache-spark

I have a 100-millions line table, I would like to know how many unique values I have on a CTAC column.
I tried :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM ( SELECT    CTAC 
       FROM      my_table
       GROUP BY  CTAC 
       HAVING    COUNT(*) > 1)
```

but this gives me an error :

```
sql.AnalysisException : cannot recognize input near '<EOF>' in subquery source
```

Can we do a subquery in spark ? If so, how ?

Which query should I try to solve my question ?

Answer (score 0):

Try differently as

```
println(dataFrame.select("CTAC").distinct.count)
```